# on click add an element to next node Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi I had started learning AngularJS a month ago, I wonder how could we add an angular directive to an element on click(ngClick/customClick).

```
<button type="button" ng-click="change()">
change this
</button>
<div class="container" ng-bind-html="element">
<ul>
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Joe</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template">
  <ul><li></li></ul>
</script>

var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.contents = ['Jack','Jenifer'];
  $scope.tmpl = "template.html";
  $scope.change = function(){
     $scope.element= "<ng-include src=\"tmpl\"></ng-include>";
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dmeLtepf/2/
I am actually looking something similar to this.. on click I should replace the existing list in the container. Thank you :)

Comment: What is the point of using an ng-include with ng-bind-template? You can just use <div class="container" ng-include="tmp1"></div>

Comment: Since you're learning, while you're at it, the preferred method for using ng-controller is with the "controller as" syntax. Great explanation here: https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: say I have a filter in the form of button and the container renders the template according some functions result.

Comment: That's fine, angular's two-way data binding will detect if the value of tmp1 changes based on a function call / filter / logic, and it will update which template is being loaded by ng-include. I'll create a demo and post it as an answer. Give me a minute

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dmeLtepf/
In this the default list should be replaced with the new one on click. This is what I am expecting. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified to simply use the `ng-include` attribute instead of trying to bind a template with an ng-include element, etc. etc.

The code would be as simple as:

```
<div ng-include="Main.template"></div>
```

Here is a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FVHwA8ljoyrO8WybEmBf?p=preview)  showing you how you can dynamically load different templates based on some a function call using some logic in the controller. Hope this helps!

**Note - This is using the "controller as" syntax as described in the initial comments.  [Link to the article here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dmeLtepf/
I am actually looking something similar to this.. on click I should replace the existing list in the container. Thank you :)